# denovo 2Gb whole genome sequencing on a small sequencer

Tags: dna-sequencing

What are the limitations of using Illumina's smaller sequencers (e.g., iSeq100, miniSeq) to do de novo whole genome sequencing on an organism with a larger genome (~2Gb)?

Naively, it seems even if I am only able to do 5Mb worth of sequencing per 24 hour run on these sequencers, after about two years of running the thing continuously, I should be able to have enough reads to be able to assemble a de novo genome sequence of a larger eukaryote (downstream bioinformatics concerns aside). Yet clearly the sequencers are never marketed like this and I'm struggling to understand why.

I am interested in GWAS on non-model vertebrates if that matters. That time frame doesn't seem crazy, as some field experiments take several years before something is publishable.

Answer (score 1):

> Yet clearly the sequencers are never marketed like this and I'm
>   struggling to understand why.

You don't see why **two years of instrument reagent costs** for a single project might be considered prohibitive?